# Cron job throwing error "service: not found [No such file or directory]" but when executed manually in terminal script works fine

Tags: files, process, cron, services, jboss

`service jbossas status` -> command will check the jbossas status

jbossas(PID) is running (if jbossas is running)

jbossas is stopped (if jbossas is stopped)

```
#!/bin/ksh
#set -x
OUT_LOG="$1"

stus=$(service jbossas status)

var=$(ps -ef | grep -i '[/]jboss')

hname=$(hostname)

if [ -z "$var" ]; then

echo "service jbossas status" >>$OUT_LOG

echo "$stus" >>$OUT_LOG

mail -s "Please check for possbile impact $(stus)" aaa@aaa.com << $OUT_LOG

else

echo "'$stus'"

fi
```

NOTE:JBOSS process is not running on server  so the o/p will be jboss is stopped .

If i execute the script manually in the shell(balck screen cmd prompt)

```
./jboss_status.ksh
```

Im receiving the mail with below subject and script is working fine

"Please check for possible impact jbossas is stopped"

but when i schedule it in the cron

```
* * * * * /aaa/jboss_status.ksh > /aaa/jboss_status.ksh.error 2>&1
```

Im receiving the mail with below subject 
"Please check for possbile impact" 
NOTE :"jbossas is stopped " is not getting printed at end of the subject

In getting below error in the error file created by cron

```
/aaa/jboss_status.ksh[20]: service: not found [No such file or directory]
```

The script is executing fine in cron but the output returned by the

```
command : service jbossas status 
op: jboss stopped
```

is not getting printed in the subject

Answer (score 1):

You may need to source your bash_profile or bash_rc at the top of your script

on ubuntu

```
source /home/<user>/.bash_profile
```

some other linuxes

```
source /home/<user>/.bash_rc
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the PATH variable for the user running the cron , it should have the path to the used script or its dependencies . Compare the paths with :

```
echo $PATH
```

under the user which you run the script manually , and with the user which run the script in the cron .

Comment: Hi Begoul , Thanks for the quick revert . im running the script  with my id  manually as well scheduled cron under my id . if $path is the issue then why for cron job scheduled for this script under my id  alone is throwing error .

i guess the issue is something related to the line 
stus=$(service jbossas status) 
as cron is throwing error as as  "service: not found [No such file or directory]"

Comment: `crontab -e` as user `SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11` The variable for SHELL mußt you adapt to your settigns.

Comment: @star just try it with the full path to `service` to verify. Check `which service` for that.

Comment: Hi jacob/Bahamut the script is working fine when ran manually but only while scheduling in cron im getting this error . if the issue is with PATH then why did the script work fine when i ran it manually ?